# A better proof for $\det(P) = \pm1$ if $P$ is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Looking for elementary proof for $\rm~det(\textbf{P})$ = $\pm 1$ if $P$ is an orthogonal matrix.  I prefer a proof without using determinant of transpose matrix.

#### My First Proof, with $\det(\textbf{P}^{t}) = \det(\textbf{P})$

If $P$ is orthogonal matrix,  $\textbf{P}^{t}=\textbf{P}^{-1}$. So,
$$\det(\textbf{P}^{t}\textbf{P})=\det(\textbf{I}) \implies \det(\textbf{P}^{t}\textbf{P}) = 1 \implies \det(\textbf{P}^{t}) \det(\textbf{P}) = 1$$
because $ \det(\textbf{P}^{t}) = \det(\textbf{P})$.
Therefore, $\det(\textbf{P}^{t})=\det(\textbf{P}) = \pm 1$.

#### My Second Proof,  without $\det(\textbf{P}^{t}) = \det(\textbf{P})$

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue for orthogonal matrix $\textbf{P}$.
$$\textbf{P}\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v},\quad\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$$
$$\implies \rVert \textbf{P}\vec{v}\lVert = \lVert \lambda\vec{v} \lVert \implies \rVert \textbf{P}\vec{v} \lVert = \rvert \lambda \ \lvert \lVert \vec{v} \rVert = 1$$
because $\lVert \vec{v} \rVert = 1$

Therefore $\lvert \lambda \rvert = 1$
because $\textbf{P}$   is orthonormal matrix.
$$\textbf{P} = \textbf{P}^{t}$$
Therefore $\textbf{P} = \textbf{U}^{t}\Lambda\textbf{U} $
$$\det(\textbf{U}^{t}\Lambda\textbf{U}) = \det(\textbf{U}^{t})\det(\Lambda)\det(\textbf{U})$$
$$\det(\textbf{U}^{t}\Lambda\textbf{U}) = \det(\textbf{U}^{t})\det(\textbf{U})\det(\Lambda)$$
$$\det(\textbf{U}^{t})\det(\textbf{U}) = 1 $$
(because $\textbf{U}$ is orthogonal matrix})

$$\det(\textbf{P}) = \det(\textbf{U}^{t}\Lambda\textbf{U}) = \det(\Lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i = \pm 1 $$
$$\implies \det(\textbf{P}) = \pm 1$$

Comment: The claim isn't true; unitary matrices have $|\det{P}| = 1$.

Comment: What you are getting is $(\det P)^2=1$, but no more than that.

Comment: thx to point it out

Comment: Shouldn't it be $P^t P = I$  instead of "$\implies P^t = P$" at the top?

Comment: And the proof is $\det(P^tP) = \det(I) \implies \det(P)^2 = 1$ which is what you already have. It is as elementary as it can get.

Comment: thx to point out other error should be$$\textbf{P}^{t} = \textbf{P}^{-1}$$

Comment: well, I'm looking for without using determinant of transpose matrix

Comment: What's wrong with determinant?

Comment: Seems to me a lot is missing here. First, it seems you are assuming $P$ has real entries, whereas unitary matrices are allowed to have nonreal (complex) entries. So, you are really asking about *orthogonal* matrices. You introduce $\Lambda$, but you never say what it is. I guess it's supposed to be a diagonal matrix, but is is true that if $P$ is orthogonal then there is an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $UPU^t$ is diagonal? or are you thinking of the theorem about *symmetric* matrices? Also, you write $U^t\Lambda P$ where I think you mean $U^t\Lambda U$.

Comment: Finally, once you get to $|\lambda|=1$ for all eigenvalues of $P$, it follows that $|\det P|=1$ and, since the entries of $P$ are real, $\det P=\pm1$.

Comment: Yup, I have a lots assumption here without explanation. First $\Lambda$ is standard notation for diagonal matrix,

Comment: Second, I use transpose instead of complex conjugate so i explicitly refer to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You can't entirely avoid complex numbers, because the eigenvalues of an (real) orthogonal matrix can be any complex numbers with absolute value one. Gerry's way of  combining with the det being real is probably the sleekest (FWIW I don't see a faster one).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a geometric argument that can be used for real orthogonal matrices: If $T:\ V\to V$ is an arbitrary linear transformation of a finite dimensional euclidean vector space $V$ then  the volumes of arbitrary measurable sets $A\subset V$, in particular of balls or cubes,  are multiplied by  $\bigl|\det(T)\bigr|$. That is to say, one has
$${\rm vol}\bigl(T(A)\bigr)=\bigl|\det(T)\bigr|\ {\rm vol}(A)\ .$$
Now an orthogonal transformation $T$ transforms the unit ball $B:=\bigl\{x\in{\mathbb R}^n\bigm| |x|\leq1\bigr\}$  onto itself, and ${\rm vol}(B)>0$. It follows that $|\det(T)\bigr|=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight from Christian Blatter, can you explain more about what is "reasonable set A"?

Comment: @bsdshell : By reasonable we imply those sets for which the notion of volume is defined, which means those functions for which the indicator function can be integrated (using the Lebesgue integral to be as general as possible).

Comment: Is this a generalization to the higher dimensions of the idea that orthogonal transformations only reflects or rotates in 2D euclidean space, and that is why the volume is invariant under the transformation?

Comment: Quick question: Is the converse true? Are all matrices with det(X)=1, orthogonal?

Answer (score 3):

The absolute value of the determinant of a real, square matrix is the volume of the parallelepiped whose sides are the columns of the matrix. For an orthogonal matrix, the columns are pairwise orthogonal unit vectors, so this parallelepiped is a cube with side length 1.  So the volume is 1, and therefore the determinant is $\pm1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $|\det(Q)|>1$, then for any positive integer $n$, $|\det(Q^n)|=|\det(Q)|^n$ will blow up. Since for any positive integer $n$, $Q^n$ is  also an orthogonal matrix, whose determinant will not blow up due to the geometric meaning of determinant, we know that $|\det(Q^n)|$ will not blow up and $|\det(Q)|=1$.